# Any reason why Chrome would be loading pages much slower than Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, browser, latency

I switch back and forth using Chrome and Firefox as my browsers. I've noticed lately that Chrome has taken awhile to load some pages even with just one tab open. Firefox doesn't do this, and loads very fast. Is this just the nature of these browsers or is it an underlying problem? I'm running Win7 as my OS on a desktop.

Comment: Page Server load, Browser Version, too many extensions, registry issues etc. can be possible problems... Just any of them can be the cause, so reinstall either of them & then check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cache** might be a reason. There is a possibility that the page you are loading has been opened earlier in Firefox and has some of its assets already cached in Firefox, so Firefox uses that copy and doesn't need to wait for the server response.

Clear both browsers' Cache and then check again.

Another reason for slower chrome might be a **lot of Extensions or Add-ons running in Background** and some of them might be *Eating up the Bandwidth* or at-least the *CPU resources* and making the loading slow.

Try **disabling the extensions**.

Comment: Only had a few extentions in Chrome and deleted them then restarted Chrome. It seemed to have helped and I didn't clear the cache but will do that if something like this arises again, thanks @lamb.

Answer (score 0):

Download (for free) [CCleaner](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/download/b097166f338b4c320427a27e5acb7655/), run it (including registry cleaner) and see if that helps.

Comment: I d/l that last week and it seemed to have helped both browsers' response time, thanks.